# R - Get substring between first occurrence and last occurrence

Tags: r, string

I'm working with long strings in R such as:

```
string <- "end of section. 3. LESSONS. The previous LESSONS are very important as seen in Figure 1. This text is also important. Figure 1: Blah blah blah".
```

I would like to extract the substring between the first occurrence of 'LESSONS' and the last occurrence of 'Figure 1', as follows:

```
"The previous LESSONS are very important as seen in Figure 1. This text is also important."
```

I tried the following but it returns the substring after the last occurence of 'LESSONS', not the first:

```
gsub(".*LESSONS (.*) Figure 1.*", "\\1", string)
#[1] "are very important as seen in Figure 1. This text is also important."
```

Also tried the following but it cuts the string after the first occurrence of 'Figure 1', not the last:

```
library(qdapRegex)
ex_between(string, "LESSONS", "Figure 1")
#[[1]]
#[1] ". The previous LESSONS are very important as seen in"
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close. Make the regex non-greedy at the before `"LESSONS"` so that it matches the first one.

Also, here you can use only `sub` instead of `gsub`.

```
sub(".*?LESSONS\\.\\s*(.*) Figure 1.*", "\\1", string)
#[1] "The previous LESSONS are very important as seen in Figure 1. This text is also important."
```

Comment: You're the best, Ronak! Thanks!

Comment: Done! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_extract` from the package `stringr` as well as positive lookbehind in `(?<=...)`and positive lookahead in `(?=...)` to define those parts of the string that *delimit* the part you want to extract:

```
str_extract(string, "(?<=LESSONS\\.\\s).*(?=\\sFigure 1)")
[1] "The previous LESSONS are very important as seen in Figure 1. This text is also important."
```

Comment: Thank you! I know `stringr` but had not used those delimiters, this was super helpful.

Comment: Please consider upvoting if you feel this answer was useful for you.